# How to convert '( '(...) '(...) ... ) to [ [...] [...] ... ] in Clojure?

Tags: list, vector, clojure

How to convert '( '(...)  '(...) ... ) to [  [...]   [...] ...  ] in Clojure ?

I have a nested list

```
(def a '( '(1 2 3 4) '(:a :b :c :d) )
```

I want to get result like this:

```
[ [1 2 3 4] [:a :b :c :d] ]
```

But when I tried to use, but innter element is still a list instead of a vector :

```
(map vec a)
;;output is ([quote (1 2 3 4)] [quote (:a :b :c :d)] )
```

but I type in REPL:

```
(vec '(1 2 3 4))
;; output is [1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: Why do you have the inner quotes? You don't have a list of lists, you have a list of quoted lists.

Comment: yeah, I should not quote inner list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to quote sublists.

```
(def a '((1 2 3 4) (:a :b :c :d)))
```

You can use mapv, which is similar to map, but returns a vector instead of a lazy sequence

```
(mapv vec a)
```